# Reverse engineer a number for Math.random() in Java, based on a random string

Tags: java, algorithm

So I have a question on a little problem I am working on.

Given a random string generated by a java program of any length e.g. `jdefreq`.

Each character within the string is generated using,

```
final String[] dict = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
        "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ",", ".", "?" };

final int dictIndex = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * dict.length);
```

I have a way to replicate `Math.random()` but I need the **exact** first number, that is used starting off within the sequence.

The way I have been trying to go about it, right now is take the first character, and loop with `Math.random()` until I get a number that can reproduce the same index of that first character, but that's not good enough since I only produce a similar number, but not the **exact** same one.

So I have came here fellow programmers !

Does anybody have any idea how / what I can do to be able to pull this off ?

Really excited to hear people's advice / their *POV* on the problem !

---

Thanks and have an awesome day !

Comment: "little problem" - I highly doubt that!

Comment: It may be hard ! But it just something that came up as a 'side' exercise in class !

Comment: Only 48 bits of entropy, should be brute-forceable.

Comment: Also note that the algorithm takes into account the system time for seed when the number was generated. I am not sure if its even possible to get the original back. Take a look: `this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());` from `Random` class

Comment: @Prashant is right: if you know approximately when the `Random` was instantiated and no numbers have been drawn from it first (or you know how many), the number of possibilities you need to try should be limited. I don’t remember the details, but a Poker site once published their source code and instantiated a new random sequence every day at midnight, making it not too hard for geeky users to guess their opponent’s hand. They had to change that very soon.

Comment: I think that after `Math.floor` big part of information is lost. So you can find only a 48+ bit set of "right" values of `Math.random` that could be close or similar answers, but definitely not exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment: there are only 2<sup>48</sup> distinct sequences that `Math.random` can produce. That's quite a lot, but not so many that you can't try all of them in a thinkable amount of time. The setup looks like

```
for (long seed = 0; seed < (1L << 48); seed++) {
    Random r = new Random(seed);
    if (generateString(r).equals(desiredString)) return seed;
}
```

where `generateString(r)` generates strings the same way except using `r.nextDouble()` instead of `Math.random()`.

Another approach would be to code the relevant setup as a satisfiability modulo theory and then throw a solver at it. Since Java's pseudorandom number generator is a linear congruential generator that doesn't use division, that part isn't too hard. Naively one might imagine that we have to implement floating-point arithmetic for `Random.nextDouble()`, but we can reason directly about ranges with respect to the 53-bit integer that `nextDouble()` generates. All in all, this is tedious but relatively straightforward because the complicated algorithm logic is encapsulated in the solver.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, it's been a long time since I've seriously programmed in Java.